# Set value of "Simple Combobox" with class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I am using the plug-in ["Simple Combobox"](https://github.com/ivkremer/jquery-simple-combobox) and have several combo-boxes (all with the same options) on a form.

I want to set the value of each combo-box using the 'val' method, for example:

```
$(selector).scombobox('val', 'opt3');
```

It works fine when I target a combobox by ID, but not by Class. [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tysonkoska/hw3zo2q5/) showing my failed attempts.

Do I need to designate a unique ID for every combo-box or can this be done using only its Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is happening because of the class conflict

If you want to set the value on all combo than use

```
$('.scombobox').scombobox('val', 'opt3');
```

That will set the property for all on that page